# TimeTask agendando Tarefas em Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou tentando montar alguns ciclos de tarefa no TimeTask para que aconteça todos os dias num determinado horário, alguém poderia me passar um tutorial ou algum exemplo que empregue essa questão ? O que acontece é que funciona, mas só uma vez, se por acaso tento fazer outra tarefa, eu não consigo.
Obrigado desde já.

## Aqui a classe que uso o TimerTask.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Timer;  
import java.util.TimerTask;  
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;
import br.com.email.mundial.Conexao;

public class DiaTeste {  

    public static final long TEMPO = ( 11 * 1440); 

    protected static final String Class = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {  
        final Connection conexao = new Conexao().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT P.duplic, "
                        + "       P.dtemissao, "
                        + "       P.dtvenc, "
                        + "       P.valor, "
                        + "       C.cliente, "
                        + "       P.obs2, "
                        + "       c.email, "
                        + "       P.codcli, "
                        + "       C.telent, "
                        + "       Nvl(P.valordesc, 0) VLDESC, "
                        + "       P.codusur, "
                        + "       P.prest, "
                        + "       P.codcob, "
                        + "       C.ieent, "
                        + "       C.bloqueio, "
                        + "       P.duplic "
                        + "       || '-' "
                        + "       || P.prest          AS TITULO, "
                        + "       P.numtransvenda, "
                        + "       P.codfilial "
                        + "FROM   pcprest P, "
                        + "       pcclient C, "
                        + "       pccob B, "
                        + "       pcfilial F "
                        + "WHERE  P.codcob = B.codcob "
                        + "       AND P.codcli = C.codcli "
                        + "       AND P.codfilial = F.codigo "
                        + "       AND  F.CODIGO = 4 "
                        + "       AND p.codcob NOT IN ( 'DEVP', 'DEVT', 'BNF', 'BNFT', "
                        + "                             'BNFR', 'BNTR', 'BNRP', 'CRED', 'DESD' ) "
                        + "       AND P.dtpag IS NULL "
                        + "       AND p.dtvenc = To_date(SYSDATE)-1000");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){

            final String cliente = rs.getString("cliente");
            final String dtvenc = rs.getString("dtvenc");
            final String valor   = rs.getString("valor");
            final String EMAIL   = rs.getString("EMAIL");
            final String duplic   = rs.getString("duplic");

            Timer timer = null;  
            if (timer == null) {  
                timer = new Timer();  
                TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {  
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

                    public void run() {   


                        try {  

                            MultiPartEmail emai = new MultiPartEmail(); //classe utilizada para permitir anexos no email  
                            emai.setDebug(true);  
                            emai.setHostName("120.0.0.0"); //servidor SMTP. Aqui usamos um do Gmail  
                            emai.setSmtpPort(25);
                            emai.setAuthentication("teste,teste.com.br", "sadsadsadsa"); // login e senha da conta Gmail  
                            emai.setSSL(false); //Autenticação de segurança SSL setada como True  
                            emai.addTo(EMAIL);
                            //  emai.addTo("dsadsadasdsa.com.br"); //nome do email que vai receber o bkp do banco de dados. Pode ser o seu para teste  
                            emai.setFrom("DSADSAD@saSAsa.com.br"); //endereço de email do remetente  
                            emai.setSubject(" Cobrança de Divida Ativa "); //assunto  
                            emai.setMsg("Prezado( a ) Senhor( a ): " + cliente

                                    +"\n\n\n Após diversos contatos telefônicos, visando uma solução rápida e eficaz quanto à necessidade de imediata liquidação por parte de V.S   .a do "
                                    + "título de crédito infra-identificado e, considerando que os referidos contatos não contaram com a colaboração e providência de V.S.a, servimo-"
                                    + "nos da presente para Notifica-lo formalmente quanto a MORA existente. \n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + " Assim, notifica-se V. As para que no prazo de 48 (quarenta e oito ) horas, contada  s do recebimento desta, proceda a liquidação do título em "
                                    + "questão, devidamente acrescido de juros, taxas de permanência e de   mais encargos, o que poderá ser feito através do boleto bancário que se "
                                    + "encontra em vosso poder ou, alternativamente por meio de depósito    bancário em favor da Notificante, através da conta bancária A SER "
                                    + "INDICADA, sob pena de não o fazendo serem adotadas medidas legais    de cobranças, tais como, inclusão em cadastro de inadimplentes, "
                                    + "remessa da cambial a cartório de protestos e, posterior envio de pendência do Dep. Jurídico. \n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + " Ressaltamos que caso deseje V.S.a promover a liquidação da pendência  ora notificada por meio de depósito na conta bancária, deve ser"
                                    + "mantido contato com nosso departamento financeiro, através do tele   fone (0xx62) 265 1001, para obtenção do valor corrigido e acrescido dos "
                                    + "encargos devidos, bem como do código identificador de depósito, permitindo assim a baixa do título e sustação das medidas de cobrança "
                                    + "acima nominadas, COMO TAMBÉM DADOS DA CONTA BANCÁRIA. \n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + " Na hipótese da dependência já se encontrar liquidada quando do recebimento da presente, favor desconsiderar o conteúdo. \n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + " Informamos mais, que caso V.S. a promova o pagamento do título em cartório, arcará na ocasião com despesas e juros cartorias, ficando"
                                    + "pendente ainda os encargos moratórios de taxa de permanência, os quais deverão ser liquidados por meio de depósito identificado junto a "
                                    + "conta bancária indicada nesta Notificação.\n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + " Certos do interesse e colaboração, desde já agradecemos  e  ficamos no aguardo da imediata solução da pendência ora apontada e noticiada.\n\n"
                                    + ""
                                    + "Duplic. Nº "+ duplic    +   "\n\nvalor da divida R$" +   valor + "\n\ncom data de vencimento para:" + dtvenc);

                            emai.send(); //envia o email  

                            try {
                                //Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
                                //preparando para inserir dados de LOG.
                                String sql = "insert into PCCLIENT" +
                                        " (LOGENVIO)" +
                                        " values (?)";
                                PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
                                stmt.setString(1, "carta1");
                                stmt.execute();
                                stmt.close();
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                System.out.println("passei pelo insert");
                            }

                            //chamar metodo  
                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                    }  
                };  

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, TEMPO, TEMPO);            
            }  

        }  

    }

}
```

Comment: Wesley, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Seria interessante se completasse o código pelo menos para não ficar um exemplo pela metade.

Comment: Wesley, fiz uma breve análise do código agora há pouco e aparentemente deveria funcionar, isto é, criar um *timer* para cada entrada no banco de dados e então executar no tempo determinado. Quando você diz que funciona só uma vez, o que exatamente ocorre? O programa executa uma vez e encerra completamente? Ou ele executa com erro das outras vezes? Qual o erro?

Comment: bom e que na verdade ele fica em Loop, nunca para, queria uma forma que ele parece assim que chegasse no ultmimo email enviado e só fizesse esse processo novamente no dia seguinte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para executar o `Timer` uma vez ao dia, o terceiro parâmetro do método do método deve ser o valor em milissegundos referente a um dia.

O método que você está usando recebe três parâmetros:

1. A tarefa a ser executada
2. O intervalo de tempo (`ms`) de agora até a primeira execução
3. O intervalo de tempo (`ms`) entre as execuções

Portanto, para executar a rotina uma vez agora e depois uma vez a cada dia, use o seguinte exemplo:

```
//quantidade de dias em milissegundos
TEMPO = 24*60*60*1000;

//executa a primeira vez agora e depois uma vez por dia
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, 0, 24*60*60*1000);
```

Se quiser executar num horário fixo, passe uma data (`java.util.Date`) com o horário desejado no segundo parâmetro. Essa data seria a da primeira execução e as demais execuções seriam sempre em intervalos 24 horas a partir dessa data.